# How respond in HTML and JSON with Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have

(Home Controller)

```
    def default

        users = Users.all

        respond_to do |format|

            format.html 
            format.json { render json: users}

        end

     end
```

and

(view)

```
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/home',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).then(response => console.log(response))
```

with the json headers but I get

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (LoginController#default is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []):
```

with the http error 406 (Not Acceptable)

Thank you for your help :)

**Edit :**

I find the problem, in fact my Rails took my request as '/homehome' I don't know why ? I change '/home' to '' in the axios url parameter and it's work now, but I still not understand what is happening ??

I have also in my web console this message

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set 
without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver
cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and
`Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under
Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Answer (score 0):

Has you ever try this config `responseType: 'json', // default` for axios, for detail you can read in the axios document.